# How to set active class in React-Router?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a navigation created using React-Router

nav.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { menu } from './menu'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import styles from './HamburgerMenu.module.scss'

const HamburgerMenu: React.FC = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = React.useState<number>(0)
  console.log(active)

  return (
    <nav>
      <ul className={styles.menu}>
        {menu.map((item, index) => (
          <li
            onClick={() => setActive(index)}
            key={item.title}
            className={styles[active === index ? 'active' : '']}
          >
            <Link to={item.link}>{item.title}</Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default HamburgerMenu
```

menu.ts:

```js
export const menu: IMenuItem[] = [
  {
    link: '/',
    title: 'главная'
  },
  {
    link: '/profile',
    title: 'профиль'
  },
  {
    link: '/discipline',
    title: 'наказания'
  },
  {
    link: '/store',
    title: 'магазин'
  },
  {
    link: '/statistics',
    title: 'статистика'
  }
]
```

main.tsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './pages/Home/Home'
import './assets/style/global.scss'
import NotFoundPage from './pages/NotFoundPage'
import Profile from './pages/Profile/Profile'

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <Home />,
    path: '/'
  },
  {
    element: <Profile />,
    path: '/profile'
  },
  {
    element: <NotFoundPage />,
    path: '*'
  }
])

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

style.scss

```
.menu {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    gap: 10;
    margin-right: 100px;

    li.nav-link-item {
        margin: 0px 50px;
        a {
            color: $white;
            opacity: 0.7;
            transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
            font-size: 20px;

            &:hover {
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }
    }

    li.nav-link-item:has(a.active) {
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: 5px solid #542c44;
        padding: 7px 42px;
    }
}
```

Layout.tsx - the page turns into it

```
import React from 'react'
import { ILayoutProps } from './Laout.type'
import Header from '../Header/Header'
import Footer from '../Footer/Footer'
import styles from './Layout.module.scss'

const Layout: React.FC<ILayoutProps> = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <div className={styles['layout']}>
            <Header />
            {children}
            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Layout
```

When switching between `'/'` and `'/profile'` the `"active"` class is constantly reset and switched to 0, if I want the `"active"` class to be added to `'/profile'`, then I need to click on it 2 times, and if I switch between `'/discipline'`, `'/store'`, `'/statistics'`, classes are assigned normally. I understand that this behavior is most likely due to the fact that `'/discipline'`, `'/store'`, `'/statistics'` are not declared pages, but what about `'/'` and `'/profile'`? Why could this be happening, and how can this be corrected?

Comment: Where are you rendering the `<HamburgerMenu>`? It's most likely remounted, which resets its local state. Instead of `useState`, use `useLocation` and match against each `item.link`.

Comment: [NavLink](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link) is your friend ^^

Comment: @Bergi `HamburgerMenu` is added to the `Header` component, and the header component is added to the `Layout` component, which includes the header, child component, and footer. I can supplement the question and insert a component `Layout` if you need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `NavLink` component which applies an [`"active"`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link#default-active-class) classname for the matched link by default, and use CSS to select the `li` element with a currently matching link.

Example:

```
const HamburgerMenu: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <nav>
      <ul className={styles.menu}>
        {menu.map((item, index) => (
          <li
            key={item.title}
            className="nav-link-item" // <-- something easily targetable
          >
            <NavLink end to={item.link}>
              {item.title}
            </NavLink>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

```css
li.nav-link-item {
  /* li styling */
}

li.nav-link-item:has(a.active) {
  /* "active" li styling overrides */
}
```

Information:

- [Navlink](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link)
- [CSS :has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)

### Demo

[image: Edit how-to-set-active-class-in-react]

[image]

Since you are using SASS, this appears to be correct CSS for what you are working with:

```
li.nav-link-item {
  margin: 0px 50px;

  a {
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.7;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
    font-size: 20px;

    &:hover {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }

  &:has(:global(a.active)) { // <-- access global non-SASS "active" class
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 5px solid #542c44;
    padding: 7px 42px;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I figured out how it works, but for some reason adding styles to the active state does not lead to anything, I can supplement my question with new styles. Also in my project there is a `Layout` component in which the page is wrapped, the component adds a header and footer, can this somehow affect the styling, and is it necessary to supplement the question with this component?

Comment: @Salivan Yes, please do edit your post to add any new and relevant information/details. If you are able to create a ***running*** codesandbox demo of your code that could also help speed up the process since we could inspect your code running live.

Comment: Added new details to the question

Comment: @Salivan If you don't mind, can you clarify here what your current observed behavior is with my code suggestion? Are you able to inspect the DOM to see what CSS is actually getting applied? I don't believe the presence of a header/footer would change the li/link styling/behavior, but better to be thorough.

Comment: Well, if the main one is active, then the active class is applied to the desired link, but for some reason the styles are not applied

Comment: @Salivan I see. I think seeing a running example would be helpful here. Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue we could inspect live? Feel free to fork my sandbox if you like since it's already setup in Typescript and React-Router-DOM.

Comment: This is a demo of my sandboxed code: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/exaple-5ttsrs?file=%2Fsrc%2Fmain.tsx%3A6%2C23

Comment: @Salivan Ok, I think I have it working with SASS for you. I've updated my answer and included a screenshot. Please take a look when you have availability.